# How to retrieve child inside another child from Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve `medicine` child, if its `created_on` time is equal to specified time. Here is my code:

```
func loadDataFromFirebase(){
 let tym = summary?.created_on
databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medical_details")
databaseRef.queryOrderedByChild("created_on").queryEqualToValue(tym).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {

            print(snapshot)
        }
    })
```

It shows a snapshot like this:

```
Snap (-KZQxDyOJ9nLyiK_l3lT) {
comments = hhf;
"created_on" = "Dec 20, 2016 4:49:11 PM";
medicine =     {
    "-KZQxDyUtdydQRdpWKNN" =         {
        dosage = " 10/300mg";
        frequency = 5;
        interval = 6;
        "number_of_tablets" = 4;
        reminder = Notification;
        tablet = "Vicodin(Hydrocodone/Acetaminophen)";
    };
    "-KZQxDy_AlMzR_L36y-R" =         {
        dosage = " 10mg";
        frequency = 6;
        interval = 5;
        "number_of_tablets" = 2;
        reminder = Notification;
        tablet = Methadone;
    };
};
"pain_level" = 2;
remedies = "Drinking Water";
"user_id" = QyKCJl3gTIa1Pl7j9GHpvnVU6Fo2;
}
```

My question is how to retrieve that `medicine` node alone, if created_on is equal to selected time?

Comment: You can get the child from 'item' once it's retrieved.

Comment: but how..?no idea...

Comment: Inside the loop you should `print(item.val())` (instead of `snapshot`).

Comment: it again retrieves the whole snapshot..but i need that "medicine" node alone..?